# LSTMで予測をしたい。

Tags: python

LSTMで予測したいと思っており、データを学習データとテストデータに分け、精度を検証しています。ゆくゆくは学習データで学習させ、データ外の範囲を予測したいと考えていますがそのようなことは可能でしょうか。ご回答よろしくお願いします。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import time

df = pd.read_csv("Book99.csv", encoding='windows-1252', parse_dates=['date'])
print(df)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

look_back = 100

sample_size = len(df) - look_back

past_size = int(sample_size*0.8)
future_size = sample_size - past_size +1


def make_dataset(raw_data, look_back=25):
    _X = []
    _y = []

    for i in range(len(raw_data) - look_back):
        _X.append(raw_data[i : i + look_back])
        _y.append(raw_data[i + look_back])
    _X = np.array(_X).reshape(len(_X), look_back, 1)
    _y = np.array(_y).reshape(len(_y), 1)

    return _X, _y

from sklearn import preprocessing

columns = list(df.columns)
del columns[0]


Xs = []
for i in range(len(columns)):
    Xs.append(preprocessing.minmax_scale(df[columns[i]]))
Xs = np.array(Xs)


X_humid, y_humid = make_dataset(Xs[1], look_back=look_back)
X_dlh, y_dlh = make_dataset(Xs[2], look_back=look_back)

X_con = np.concatenate([X_humid,X_dlh], axis=2)

X = X_humid
y = y_dlh


X_past = X[:past_size]
X_future = X[past_size-1:]
y_past = y[:past_size]
y_future = y[past_size-1:]


X_train = X_past
y_train = y_past

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam


def create_LSTM_model():
    input = Input(shape=(np.array(X_train).shape[1], np.array(X_train).shape[2]))
    x = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LSTM(64)(x)
    output = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
    model = Model(input, output)
    return model

model = create_LSTM_model()
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='mean_squared_error')

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=64, verbose=1)

predictions = model.predict(X_past)
future_predictions = model.predict(X_future)


plt.figure(figsize=(18, 9))
plt.plot(df['date'][look_back:], y, color="b", label="true_cloud_cover")
plt.plot(df['date'][look_back:look_back + past_size], predictions, color="r", linestyle="dashed", label="prediction")
plt.plot(df['date'][-future_size:], future_predictions, color="g", linestyle="dashed", label="future_predisction")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

結果
[image: 結果]